# Empty space with rectangular array and matshow

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a heatmap of some answers I got from a questionnaire, using python and matplotlib.

The matrix should be 15x30, but the result is a 30x30 matrix.

Result: [wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YXJ4.png)

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

m = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5],
    [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,8,6,4,1,3],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,9,8,7,6,2],
    [6,7,8,9,10,10,9,8,7,6,7,8,6,1,4],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,7,7,7,7,7],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,8,8,8,8,8],
    [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,9,9,9,9],
    [7,3,1,9,4,6,8,2,5,10,4,4,4,5,7],
    [1,1,2,3,5,8,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,4,7],
    [7,8,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,9,9,9,9,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5],
    [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,8,6,4,1,3],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,9,8,7,6,2],
    [6,7,8,9,10,10,9,8,7,6,7,8,6,1,4],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,7,7,7,7,7],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,8,8,8,8,8],
    [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,9,9,9,9],
    [7,3,1,9,4,6,8,2,5,10,4,4,4,5,7],
    [1,1,2,3,5,8,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,4,7],
    [7,8,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,9,9,9,9,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5],
    [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,8,6,4,1,3],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,9,8,7,6,2],
    [6,7,8,9,10,10,9,8,7,6,7,8,6,1,4],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,7,7,7,7,7],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,8,8,8,8,8],
    [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,9,9,9,9],
    [7,3,1,9,4,6,8,2,5,10,4,4,4,5,7],
    [1,1,2,3,5,8,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,4,7],
    [7,8,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,9,9,9,9,9]]

person = []
p = 1
for column in m:
    person.append('person' + str(p))
    p += 1
x_pos = np.arange(len(person))

question = []
i = 1
for row in m:
    question.append('question' + str(i))
    i += 1
y_pos = np.arange(len(question))


Cmap =plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn' , np.max(m)-np.min(m)+1)
mat = plt.matshow(m,cmap=Cmap,vmin = np.min(m)-.5, vmax = np.max(m)+.5)
cax = plt.colorbar(mat, ticks=np.arange(np.min(m),np.max(m)+5))

plt.xticks(x_pos, question, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(y_pos, person)

plt.show()

print(person)
print(question)
```

If I remove X_pos I get the right matrix, but then there are no labels.
If i manually make 15 labels like

```
Question = ['Question 1', 'Question 2',...]
```

Then I only get 15 labels, but still a 30x30matrix.

What is causing this problem in my code? And how do I fix this?

General code feedback is also welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the two for loops which suggest to do something different than they are doing actually.

In a loop like `for Ferrari in ["bike", "bus", "caravan"]:` you will never get a Ferrari out, even if you call it like this.

So in both loops you are looping over the rows of the matrix, even if you call the loop variable differently.

A good way to tackle the problem is to make the input list a numpy array. You can then iterate over its shape to obtain the ticklabels.

So a solution can look something like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5],
    [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,8,6,4,1,3],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,9,8,7,6,2],
    [6,7,8,9,10,10,9,8,7,6,7,8,6,1,4],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,7,7,7,7,7],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,8,8,8,8,8],
    [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,9,9,9,9],
    [7,3,1,9,4,6,8,2,5,10,4,4,4,5,7],
    [1,1,2,3,5,8,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,4,7],
    [7,8,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,9,9,9,9,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5],
    [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,8,6,4,1,3],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,9,8,7,6,2],
    [6,7,8,9,10,10,9,8,7,6,7,8,6,1,4],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,7,7,7,7,7],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,8,8,8,8,8],
    [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,9,9,9,9],
    [7,3,1,9,4,6,8,2,5,10,4,4,4,5,7],
    [1,1,2,3,5,8,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,4,7],
    [7,8,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,9,9,9,9,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5],
    [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,8,6,4,1,3],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,9,8,7,6,2],
    [6,7,8,9,10,10,9,8,7,6,7,8,6,1,4],
    [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,7,7,7,7,7],
    [3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,8,8,8,8,8],
    [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,9,9,9,9],
    [7,3,1,9,4,6,8,2,5,10,4,4,4,5,7],
    [1,1,2,3,5,8,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,4,7],
    [7,8,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,9,9,9,9,9]]

#make m a numpy array
m = np.array(m)
#assume there are as many persons as rows in the array (=30)
persons = list(map(lambda x: "person {}".format(x+1), range(m.shape[0])))
#assume there are as many questions as columns in the array (=15)
questions = list(map(lambda x: "question {}".format(x+1), range(m.shape[1])))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Cmap =plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn' , np.max(m)-np.min(m)+1)
mat = ax.matshow(m,cmap=Cmap,vmin = np.min(m)-.5, vmax = np.max(m)+.5)
cax = fig.colorbar(mat, ticks=np.arange(np.min(m),np.max(m)+5))

plt.xticks(range(len(questions)), questions, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(range(len(persons)), persons)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: your explanation is very concise and clear, thank you!